# Store value in session variable in java script function on button click

Tags: html, jsp

I want to store rating value in jsp session variable inside the java script function for using in testOpeartion page

I tried this way but not storing any value "UserRating" session variable

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Registration Page</title>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function SetRating() 
        {
            var rating = document.getElementById("ratingValue").value;

            <%
              request.setAttribute("UsaerRating",rating);
            %>
        }
    }
    </script>
</head>


<body>

    <form method="post" action="testOperation">
        <input type="text" id="ratingValue" onclick="doDisplay(this);" />
        <input type="Button" onclick="SetRating();" value="Set Rating"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**[From this link](http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=1300197)**

> It's not possible to set any session variables directly from
>   javascript as it is purely a client side technology. You can use AJAX
>   though to asyncronously send a request to a servlet running on the
>   server and then add the data to the session from within the servlet.
>   So you wouldn't be using javascript to do the actual setting of
>   session variables but it would look like it is.

You can also get more details from **[THIS LINK](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/Java/J2EE/JSP/Q_21736400.html)**